# Remove duplicate events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, rrule

Problem: 
I'm using FullCalendar 4 an i want to create an "appointment calendar" and i'm using rrule for holding free spaces to choose.

If i add a new appointment for a date, i want to remove the existing free space and insert a new event.

Like: 
start: 2019-10-10T10:00
title: Free space

start: 2019-10-10T10:00
title: blocked for client

The first one should be disappear and the second one should be displayed.

Now 2 events are shown for the same time.

How can i fix this?

EDIT:

So, first event is using rrule and it repeats every monday, tuesday and friday.

But i've also an event on tuesday at 7am (the second one). Now, i want to remove the event using rrule on this date.

How can i do this?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'rrule'],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    defaultDate: '2019-09-12',
    editable: true,
    events: [
      {
        "title": "Free",
        rrule: {
          freq: 'weekly',
          byweekday: ['mo', 'tu', 'fr'],
          dtstart: '2019-09-02T07:00',
          until: '2022-06-01'
        },
      },
      {
        "title": "Blocked",
        "type": "call",
        "start": "2019-09-03T07:00"
      }
    ],
    eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: false
    },
    eventColor: '#378006',
    eventClick: function (info) {
      alert('Event: ' + info.event.start);
      alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
      alert('View: ' + info.view.type);

      // change the border color just for fun
      info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
    },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Using events to represent free time isn't a good idea. A free slot should be represented by the **absence** of an event. See this answer for a better pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58164691/5947043

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it's not the way i want. 

I just want to show the free slots like this (free: blue, taken: orange) https://imgur.com/0VJ70k4 - Any idea how i can realize this?

Comment: Change default background colour of the calendar to blue, then the free spaces will be blue. Doing what you're asking by using events is going to create more problems than it solves

Comment: Just another question, how can i remove a duplicate event? I mean 2 events on one startTime. I just want to show only one.

Comment: Since I don't know how the events got there, I can't really tell you how to remove any of them. I'd need proper sample data and calendar code in order to understand the issue (i.e. a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem).

Comment: @ADyson Just edited the question, can you please take a look?

Comment: You probably need an RRULE exception. See https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/exrule.html. This is the kind of thing I mean when I talk about using events to represent free spaces starting to cause extra problems...if you just had an empty space marking the available slot then this issue would not arise.

Comment: And since you appear to have a fixed, repeating pattern for your available slots, then as an alternative approach you could close off all other regularly unavailable slots using the [businessHours](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours) feature (as mentioned in the link I provided in my first comment), leaving just the ones within the business hours to be selectable.

Comment: Hi, have the same problem, how did you solve it. mate?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're looking for is EXDATE. I'm not a FullCalendar user, but from a quick look at the docs it appears that you're using the rrule plugin, which connects to this library: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule

EXDATE is shown there, but it appears to me that the rrule plugin probably doesn't give you access to that functionality (as it supports creating an RRule, not an RRuleSet). If you can use EXDATE, that fits your use case beautifully.

Otherwise, I think your best option is to split the recurring event when this happens -- end it on the appointment before the one that has been booked, and create a new event that starts on the next open slot. For example:

```
events: [
      {
        "title": "Free",
        rrule: {
          freq: 'weekly',
          byweekday: ['mo', 'tu', 'fr'],
          dtstart: '2019-09-02T07:00',
          until: '2019-09-04'
        },
      },
      {
        "title": "Blocked",
        "type": "call",
        "start": "2019-09-06T07:00"
      },
      {
        "title": "Free",
        rrule: {
          freq: 'weekly',
          byweekday: ['mo', 'tu', 'fr'],
          dtstart: '2019-09-09T07:00',
          until: '2022-06-01'
        },
      }
    ]
```

Note that I've moved the "Blocked" appointment for this example so I could actually show what I described. Since in your example the blocked appointment is the second in the series, it would make more sense to just have two events (first Free slot and the Blocked one) and a recurring series for the rest.